# Crear login con tabla personalizada en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, login

estoy creando un login usando mi propia tabla, asi como mi propio controlador para agregar los usuarios y realizar el logeo, pude registrar los usuarios pero no me reconoce para hacer el login, ademas necesito poder obtener los datos de cual es el usuario que esta logueado en ese momento, dejo el modelo y el controlador que estoy usando para ver si por favor me pueden ayudar a corregir lo que este haciendo mal.

Este es el modelo de donde quiero guardar y obtener los datos, cabe decir que uso columnas distintas a las provistas por el auth de laravel, en ves del email tengo AliasUsu para el usuario y en password tengo ClaveUsu, y mi llave primaria es CodUsu, todo esto por especificaciones que debo cumplir en donde trabajo.

**EL MODELO**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{

    protected $table='Usuarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'CodUsu', 'CedUsu', 'NombUsu','ApeUsu','CodCargo','ClaveUsu','CodTipUsu','AliasUsu',
    ];
}
```

**EL CONTROLADOR**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Usuario;
use App\TipoUsuario;
use App\Cargo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginUsuarioController extends Controller
{
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $tipousuario=TipoUsuario::all();
        $cargo=Cargo::all();
        $usuario=Usuario::all();
        return view('auth.register',compact('tipousuario','cargo','usuario'));
    }


    public function RegistroUsuario(Request $request)
    {
        $validacion = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'CodUsu'    => ['required','string'],
            'NombUsu'   => ['required','string'],
            'ApeUsu'    => ['required','string'],
            'CodCargo'  => ['required','string'],
            'ClaveUsu'  => ['required','string','min:8'],
            'CodTipUsu' => ['required','string'],
            'CedUsu'    => ['required','string'],
            'AliasUsu'  => ['required','string'],
        ]);
        if($validacion->fails())
        {
            return redirect('registro')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validacion);
        }

        $user = new Usuario();
        $user->CodUsu = $request->CodUsu;
        $user->NombUsu = $request->NombUsu;
        $user->ApeUsu = $request->ApeUsu;
        $user->CodCargo = $request->CodCargo;
        $user->ClaveUsu = bcrypt($request->ClaveUsu);
        $user->CodTipUsu = $request->CodTipUsu;
        $user->CedUsu = $request->CedUsu;
        $user->AliasUsu = $request->AliasUsu;
        $user->save();

        return redirect('sistema');
    }

    public function LoginUsuario()
    {
        $credenciales = $this->Validate(request(),
            [
                'AliasUsu'  => ['required','string'],
                'ClaveUsu'  => ['required','string','min:8'],
            ]);

        if(Auth::attempt($credenciales))
        {
            return redirect('sistema');
        }
        else
        {
            return back()
            ->withErrors(['AliasUsu'=>trans('auth.failed')])
            ->withInput(request(['AliasUsu']));
        }
    }
}
```